# How to select the correct range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data in Google Sheets and I'm trying to run a pivot table.  The problem is that the title is on cell a1 but data doesn't start until a60.  I don't want to include the data in cells a2 through a59.  If I run the pivot on a60 to a102 then it thinks a60 is the title and doesn't include it.  How do I tell sheets to use a1+a60-a102?

Comment: pls share a copy/dummy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

if this would not be a pivot table you would need to do this:

```
={a1; a60:A102}
```

the best workaround you can ever have is to paste this on some new sheet (which you can hide) and then build your pivot table from there